# Why if I click on cancel for the last confirm it wont delete any records at all?

Tags: javascript

I'm submitting a form and deleting records from a table.
Before I delete these records I confirming deleting these records.
Its deleting the records when I confirm , but when I have more than 1 record
check to delete and I confirm 1 but cancel the next one it does not delete 
any records.

It seems if the last confirm is cancel then it wont delete anything,
and if the last confirm is true then it will delete all the check records.

Why if I click on cancel for the last confirm it wont delete any records at all?

```
function sub_keys() { 
  var Ctimes = $(".checking_id");
  var Ttimes = $(".timebox");
  var Ntimes = $(".Namebox");

  for (i = 0; i < Ttimes.length; i++) {
    var value1 = Ttimes[i].value;
    var value2 = Ntimes[i].value;
    var value3 = Ctimes[i].checked;

    if(value3) {
      var con = confirm('Are you sure you delete ' 
                        + value2 + 'for time '
                        + value1 + ' ?' );
    }
  }

  if(con) {
    var formData = $("#confrm_key").serializeArray();
    var URL = 'delete_table.cfc?method=getkeyDetail';

    $.post(URL, formData, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        if(data!=0) {
          alert('Selected records deleted successfully');

          var array = data.split(",");
          for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            $( "#hd"+array[i] ).hide();
          }
        }
        //data: Data from Server
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('Error while deleting records');
    });         
}   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the result you're saving it to `con`. Each time you do this in your loop you're overwriting the previous answer. Hence, when you check the answer in the `if` block, you're really only checking the last answer.

```
for (i = 0; i < Ttimes.length; i++) {
 var value1 = Ttimes[i].value;
 var value2 = Ntimes[i].value;
 var value3 = Ctimes[i].checked;
 if (value3) {

     var con = confirm('Are you sure you delete ' + value2 + 'for time ' + value1 + ' ?')
 }
}

if (con) {}
```

You probably want to move that `if` into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through all the items and look for checked items, and show a confirm box for each one. The result of the confirmation is stored in the `con` variable, overwriting any previous value.

Then you check the value in the `con` variable and proceed with posting the form if it is true, but the variable only contains the value from the last confirm.

To allow the user to confirm each checked item, you should check the result after each confirmation, and collect the items that the user allowed to be deleted by for example putting them in an array. Example:

```
var del = [];
for (i = 0; i < Ttimes.length; i++) {
  var value1 = Ttimes[i].value;
  var value2 = Ntimes[i].value;
  var value3 = Ctimes[i].checked;
  if (value3){
    var con = confirm('Are you sure you delete ' + value2 + 'for time '+ value1 + ' ?' );
    if (con) {
      del.push(value1); // keep whatever you need for identifying the item
    }
  }
}
if (del.length) {
  // here you would delete items specified in the array
}
```